# Topology of compactification of upper half plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

"A primer on mapping class groups" authors defined the topology on $\overline{\mathbb{H}^2}$. I am unable to visualize the open sets there. I would appreciate it if someone helps me to understand the topology on $\overline{\mathbb{H}^2}$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to math.stackexchange. In this context the compactification of the upper half plane is homeomorphic to the closed disk. It may be easier for you to visualize compactification in the Poincare model of hyperbolic space by applying the Cayley transform to the upper half plane.

Comment: How good is your topology? Do you understand the concept of "subspace topology"?

Comment: Yes, I do understand subspace topology. Is that come directly from there? Still, I have a problem understanding the topology of $\overline{\mathbb{H}^2}$.